# Did those who lose smell due to covid regain it after all?

Tags: covid-19, smell, taste

We know people for example can lose taste or smell due to covid, some have this even for months, but is there data if people eventually do get this senses back or not?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [summary](https://www.beckershospitalreview.com/public-health/when-will-smell-taste-come-back-5-covid-19-questions-answered.html) of one study:

> Of 2,581 COVID-19 patients studied, 95 percent of patients regained their sense of smell within six months, according to the study in the Journal of Internal Medicine.

The study appears to be [this one](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33403772/) (on patients from continental Europe) and it has more details even its abstract:

> A total of 328 patients (24.1%) did not subjectively recover olfaction 60 days after the onset of the dysfunction. The mean duration of self-reported OD [olfactory dysfunction] was 21.6 ± 17.9 days. [...] At 60 days and 6 months, 15.3% and 4.7% of anosmic/hyposmic patients did not objectively recover olfaction, respectively.

I'm not sure if there's any study that has tracked those <5% who had not recovered at 6 months for a longer period.

In general, there are more studies on short[er] term recovery, e.g. [one in the US](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7341046/) which also has a summary of
other studies:

> Initial publications from Europe and Asia report higher rates of recovery. A French study of PCR-tested patients showed 98% experiencing a complete subjective recovery within 28 days, with mean duration of anosmia near 9 days. Workers in the United Kingdom repeated surveys 1 week after initial survey, revealing that 80% had experienced some recovery, while only 17% remained anosmic. They also noted a “plateau” in recovery after approximately 3 weeks, with a 70% recovery rate for those with anosmia of 3 or more weeks duration. Similarly, a study from Korea using daily phone surveys of almost 500 newly diagnosed COVID-19 patients showed median duration of anosmia or ageusia of 7 days, and almost all recovering within 3 weeks. [...]
>
> This study presents 1-month follow-up of patients with chemosensory changes participating in a large national longitudinal survey during the COVID-19 pandemic. Despite the severity of smell and taste loss experienced by most patients, nearly three-quarters will recover to normal or near-normal chemosensation within 2 months. The continued improvement noted between 14-day and 1-month surveys suggests that ongoing recovery is still in progress. Long term recovery and treatment effects will be a topic of further investigation.